# Store conversation data with bot as entity into Azure storage table (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, botframework, bots

I am currently working on Bot, in my project I want to store the bot data (i.e. the user, conversation, and private conversation property bags) basically what the user input and response returned in azure storage using Node.js. I am able to log on the console but not into the azure storage.

Please tell me how to implement the above concept.

Comment: Try using `session.userData()`. For more info check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state#storage-containers

Comment: You want to keep a log of the whole conversation history, or just parts of it?

Comment: @JasonSowers log the whole conversation history

Answer (score 1):

For storing conversation state data in Azure Table Storage, you can leverage [Manage custom state data with Azure Table storage for Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-state-azure-table-storage) with a ease.

To store whole conversation message history, you can leverage `receive` and `send` middleware, add custom logic to insert the history to talbe storage. Please consider following code snippet:

```
bot.use({
    receive: (evt, next) => {
        console.log(evt);
        if (evt.type == 'message') {
            azureTableClient.insertOrReplace(evt.address.user.id + `-` + new Date().valueOf(), evt.type, `[USER to BOT]: ${evt.text}`, false, ((err, etag, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(er)
                }
            }))
        }
        next();
    },
    send: (evt, next) => {
        // console.log(evt);
        azureTableClient.insertOrReplace(evt.address.user.id + `-` + new Date().valueOf(), evt.type, `[BOT to USER]: ${evt.text}`, false, ((err, etag, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(er)
            }
        }))
        next();
    }
})
```